# Abort trap: 6, using memcpy to copy an array

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, memcpy

I'm trying to learn how to copy a space in memory that was allocated with malloc. I'm assuming the best way to go about this would be to use memcpy.

I am more familiar with Python. The equivalent of what I'm trying to do in Python would be:

```
import copy

foo = [0, 1, 2]
bar = copy.copy(foo)
```

Here is was I have so far.

```
/* Copy a memory space
 * */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    // initialize a pointer to an array of spaces in mem
    int *foo = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
    int i;

    // give each space a value from 0 - 2
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        foo[i] = i;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        printf("foo[%d]: %d\n", i, foo[i]);

    // here I'm trying to copy the array of elements into 
    // another space in mem
    // ie copy foo into bar
    int *bar;
    memcpy(&bar, foo, 3 * sizeof(int));

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        printf("bar[%d]: %d\n", i, bar[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this script is as follows:

```
foo[0]: 0
foo[1]: 1
foo[2]: 2
Abort trap: 6
```

I'm compiling the script with `gcc -o foo foo.c`. I'm on a 2015 Macbook Pro.

My questions are:

1. Is this the best way to copy an array that was created with malloc?
2. What does `Abort trap: 6` mean?
3. Am I just misunderstand what `memcpy` does or how to use it?

Kind regards,

Marcus Shepherd

Comment: `bar` has no memory allocated to it, it is just an uninitialised pointer. When you have done that (as you did for `foo`), drop the `&` and use `memcpy(bar, foo, 3 * sizeof(int));`

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you so much. Post as an answer if you want the rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `bar` has no memory allocated to it, it is just an uninitialised pointer.

You should do that as you did with `foo` earlier

```
int *bar = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
```

And then you need to drop the `&` address-of operator as

```
memcpy(bar, foo, 3 * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Ahh, I was under the assumption that the `size` parameter to memcpy, would allocate that memory for me. Also, thought that malloc would initialize the pointer for me, since it `returns a pointer to the new memory space`.

Comment: The only C copy function AFAIK that allocates memory is `strdup`. It takes no `size` argument, but relies on finding the `nul` string teminator.